# How to remove .php extension and add slash with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to put together some `.htaccess` code that will turn `example.com/login.php/register.php` into `example.com/login/register`. I've tried varous approaches, but each hasn't worked quite right, from 500 [server] errors on subfolders to issues with the trailing slash, etc...

Comment: paste the code please

Comment: duplicate of so many previous posts i don't know which one to pick

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1.php/$2.php

Comment: i need the following result example.com/login/register/. help me

Comment: have you write `RewriteEngine on` on top?

Comment: I see too many php's in "example.com/login.php/register.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all  **example.com/login.php/register.php** is not a valid URL at all, first fix the URL and then

TRY  ( this will rewrite `/register.php` URL into `/register` )

```
#mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /[project_root_folder_name]/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [NC]
```

Comment: i want remove .php extension t the following url example.com/login.php/register.php

Comment: i need remove .php from the example.com/login.php/register.php/ dynamicaaly using htaccess help me

Comment: Your URL is wrong...'login.php/register.php' <-- what kind of URL this is

Comment: URL is valid, but I would like to see how it is designed

Comment: @diEcho folder names can contain periods. Many websites are stored in folders which look like their domain names `/www/example.com/index.php`. The operating system can tell it's a directory and not a file.

Comment: i am not adding any index.php file

Comment: do then : `RewriteRule ^/login/register/?$ /login.php/register.php  [NC] `

Comment: i got this error Not Found

The requested URL /login.php/register.php was not found on this server.